# How to iterate through two array and compare their elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to compare each element of two arrays.
Person writes down something in input. I want to compare what person had written with another phrase. The idea I took from this site https://lingua.com/german/dictation/ , you can check to understand what i want. It is kind of dictation, person writes down something and at the end he can check mistakes and so on.
I tried to realize function with two different ways, but it does not work

```
let [value, setValue] = useState("currentValue")
let [correctText, setCorrectText] = useState("Every day I work hard to achive my goals")
let [answer, setAnswer] = useState<string[]>([])
// first variant
let compare = () => {
        let correctTextValue = correctText.split(" ")
        let valueArray = value.split(" ")
        let arr = []
        for (let i=0; i<correctTextValue.length; i++) {
            for (let j=0; j<valueArray.length; j++) {
                if (correctTextValue[i]===valueArray[j]) {
                    arr.push(valueArray[j])
                }
                else {
                    arr.push(correctTextValue[j]
            }
        }
        }
        setAnswer([...answer, ...arr])
    }

//second variant
let compare = () => {
        let correctTextValue = correctText.split(" ")
        let valueArray = value.split(" ")
        let arr = []
        for (let i=0; i<correctTextValue.length; i++) {
            for (let j=0; j<valueArray.length; j++) {
                if (correctTextValue[i]===valueArray[j]) {
                     setAnswer([...answer, valueArray[j]])
                }
                else {
                     setAnswer([...answer, correctTextValue[j]])
            }
        }
        }
    }
// this is simple jsx code
<input value={value} onChange={e=>setValue(e.target.value)}/>
<button onClick={() => compare()}>Submit</button>
<div>{answer.map(el=><span> {el} </span>)}</div>
```

Comment: Please include where it currently fails and the expected result. Don't expect people on SO to read through other websites and merely guess what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok.  for example, i have a phrase in array. Person writes something in input. My goal is to compare the phrase from array with the phrase from input. I used two array with method for to get such result

Comment: Fine, I think I got this. However, why do you insist on comparing _words_? Wouldn't it be sufficient to just use `===` to compare the phrase with the input? E. g.: `correctText === value`?

Comment: In result I want to show each mistake which user made. For example instead of "Hello, my friend", he wrote "Hillo, my friend", and I want to underline the place where he is mistaken. That is why I need to check every word and if they are not equal to add style "underline"

Comment: `but it does not work`: how? What exactly isn't working? What's the actual result vs expected result? Is there an error in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated version of your code that should work (if I understood correctly). It compares the words from `correctText` and `value` word by word and marks different words as `isCorrect: false`. It then uses that information inside the JSX to add underline styles to incorrect words.

```
let [value, setValue] = useState("")
let [correctText, setCorrectText] = useState("Every day I work hard to achive my goals")
let [answer, setAnswer] = useState([])

let compare = () => {
  let correctTextValue = correctText.split(" ")
  let valueArray = value.split(" ")
  let arr = correctTextValue.map((word, index) => {
    if (word === valueArray[i]) {
      return {
        isCorrect: true,
        word: word
      };
    }
    return {
      isCorrect: false,
      word: valueArray[i]
    };
  });
  setAnswer(arr);
}


<input value={value} onChange={e=>setValue(e.target.value)}/>
<button onClick={() => compare()}>Submit</button>
<div>{
  answer.map(el => {
    return el.isCorrect
      ? <span>el.word</span>
      : <span style="text-decoration:underline">el.word</span>
  })
}</div>
```

Comment: @Fydor In that case please accept the answer so that others can use it as a solution (and I get some points ;) )

Answer (score 0):

```
t.fail = () => {throw Error("Unit test failed.")};
t.seqsUnequal = (a, b) => {
  /* if (a === b) return false; */
  let value, done;
  const b_iter = b[Symbol.iterator]();
  for (const a_elt of a) {
    ({value, done} = b_iter.next());
    if (done) return "b short";
    if (value !== a_elt)
      return `different values ${typeof value}:${typeof a_elt}`;
  };
  ({value, done} = b_iter.next());
  if (! done) return "a short";
  return false
};
t.seqsEqual = (a, b) => ! t.seqsUnequal(a, b);
t.exp_seq_0 = ["Greens"];
if (! t.seqsEqual(t.exp_seq_0, t.exp_seq_0)) t.fail();
if (! t.seqsEqual([], [])) t.fail();
if (t.seqsEqual(["foo"], [])) t.fail();
if (t.seqsEqual([], [0])) t.fail();
if (! t.seqsEqual(["fox", "went", "out", "on", "a", "winter's", "night"]
, ["fox", "went", "out", "on", "a", "winter's", "night"])) t.fail();
```

The above code will shallow-compare any two iterables for equality. But given that you know that you have arrays, you can use indexing, for a much simpler solution.

Comment: Not downvoted, but this produces wrong results in some settings: `t.seqsUnequal([NaN], [NaN])` returns `different values NaN:NaN`. It's an edge case, though. Just thought you might be interested.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, it's good for readers to know about NaN and how it doesn't equal itself according to ===. If someone were to use my comparator and expected some of the values to be NaN, we'd have to decide whether it should follow the convention that NaN doesn't equal NaN, or should consider different tokens of NaN to be equal in value, for the purposes of the use case.